# How to fix ArgumentException in Windows-API-Code-Pack?

Tags: c#, shell, plinq, windows-api-code-pack

I've created an application that reads properties from files using the Windows-API-Code-Pack from [this](https://github.com/contre/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1) package. I'm having an issue when retrieving properties

```
var width = fileInfo.Properties.GetProperty(SystemProperties.System.Video.FrameWidth).ValueAsObject;
```

The code breaks here giving me

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.PropertySystem.ShellPropertyFactory.GenericCreateShellProperty[T](PropertyKey propKey, T thirdArg)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.PropertySystem.ShellProperties.GetProperty(PropertyKey key)
```

This happens mostly when calling this portion of a code in a PLINQ

```
.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(_maxConcurrentThreads).ForAll(...)
```

even if the degree is set to 1. How can I solve it?

Comment: It sounds like the library isn't thread safe. Do you see it if you don't use PLinq at all?

Comment: I've done many tries but never saw it when not using PLINQ. If it's not thread safe, what could I do to make it safe? Can I use locks around my code? Or I would need to modify the source?

Comment: I would suggest downloading the code from the repo and referencing that instead of the package, and debugging it, then you'll be able to see what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

To extend on your existing answer, switching the Dictionary to a ConcurrentDictionary would also solve the problem and remove the need for locks.

```
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, Func<PropertyKey, ShellPropertyDescription, object, IShellProperty>> _storeCache
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Func<PropertyKey, ShellPropertyDescription, object, IShellProperty>>();
...

    private static IShellProperty GenericCreateShellProperty<T>(PropertyKey propKey, T thirdArg)
    {
       ...

        Func<PropertyKey, ShellPropertyDescription, object, IShellProperty> ctor;
        ctor = _storeCache.GetOrAdd((hash, (key, args) -> {
            Type[] argTypes = { typeof(PropertyKey), typeof(ShellPropertyDescription), args.thirdType };
            return ExpressConstructor(args.type, argTypes);
        }, {thirdType, type});

        return ctor(propKey, propDesc, thirdArg);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following [stuartd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43846/stuartd) suggestion I was able to solve this issue by modifying the source code of the package and adding locks in [this code](https://github.com/contre/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1/blob/master/source/WindowsAPICodePack/Shell/PropertySystem/ShellPropertyFactory.cs) at lines 57 and 62, like this

```
lock (_storeCache)
{
    if (!_storeCache.TryGetValue(hash, out ctor))
    {
        Type[] argTypes = { typeof(PropertyKey), typeof(ShellPropertyDescription), thirdType };
        ctor = ExpressConstructor(type, argTypes);
        lock (_storeCache)
            _storeCache.Add(hash, ctor);
    }
}
```

Comment: The inner lock is unnecessary, you are already in a exclusive section from the outer lock, the inner lock does nothing. A better idea might be to get rid of the lock and replace the `Dictionary` with a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)